# How to show QGIS plugin dialog always on top?

Tags: pyqgis

Is it possible to define for a pyqgis plugin, that the plugin dialog is always shown on top, after starting it from the toolbar?

Comment: This is rather a pyqt question and not really related to pyQGIS. Have a look at the following links at stackoverflow -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925015/pyqt-always-on-top or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850584/pyqt4-how-can-i-toggle-the-stay-on-top-behavior

Comment: Just watch Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint because it will be above all windows, even non QGIS ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by Nathan W, use Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint in your **init** function:

```
    class MyCustomDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
        def __init__(self, iface):
            QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, None, Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
            ...
```

But it will stay on top of not only this and every other application you have.

Comment: yes, that's what I want - have it always on top. Works well - thanks a lot!